# How to enforce iframe in compatibility mode in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

I have setup IE11 browser in compatibility mode through code. It's working fine but when a page has iframe the content inside the iframe coming in standard mode only. Is there any way to enforce iframe also in compatibility mode when main page is opening on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this as the first line in the meta head section..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

**or**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatibility" content="IE=5" />;
```

Comment: Where to add this line?

Comment: @Joy it goes in the <head> section of your htmls page. here is an example. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_meta

Comment: My question is different. I'm asking "How to enforce iframe in compatibility mode" not the page. As I have mentioned, my page is already working fine.